# Codable class doesn't conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

Try to add enum Codingkeys inside struct, But it show error Codable doesn't conform Decodable.

Why am i getting conform decodable error? Should i seperate the struct ?

```
struct Model: Codable {
    let aps: Aps
    let link: String?
    let checkAction: String?
   
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case aps ,link, alert,sound,title,body
           case checkAction = "gcm.notificaiton.check_action"
    }
    
    struct Aps: Codable {
        let alert: Alert
        let sound: String?
       
        
        struct Alert: Codable {
            let title: String?
            let body: String?
        }
    }
   

}
```

Is it a must to seperate the struct like below ?

```
struct FCMModel: Codable {
    let aps: Aps
    let link: String?
    let checkAction: String?
   
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case aps ,link
           case checkAction = "gcm.notificaiton.check_action"
    }
    

}
struct Aps: Codable {
    let alert: Alert
    let sound: String?
   
    
    struct Alert: Codable {
        let title: String?
        let body: String?
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first solution you need to separate the CodingKeys enum you have into one enum per struct but it looks like you don't need any CodingKeys for the inner types so you could simply strip the enum so it looks like the one in the second solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to separate the structs. The error occurs because you have added too many keys in the `CodingKeys` enum. If you keep only the required ones, then it will work:

```
struct Model: Codable {
    let aps: Aps
    let link: String?
    let checkAction: String?
   
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case aps ,link
           case checkAction = "gcm.notificaiton.check_action"
    }
    
    struct Aps: Codable {
        let alert: Alert
        let sound: String?
       
        
        struct Alert: Codable {
            let title: String?
            let body: String?
        }
    }
}
```

`alert`, `sound` etc are not coding keys of `Model`. They are coding keys of `Aps`. It is not necessary to specify them in `Aps`, because they are the same as the property names.